# How can I increase and synchronize primary keys of two tables at the same time with triggers?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, triggers

I have two independent database tables to store personal and address information about employees of a company as shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Person]
(
    [BusinessEntityID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [NationalIDNumber] [int] NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Student] 
         PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([BusinessEntityID] ASC)
                     WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                           IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                           ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Address]
(
    [AddressID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AddressLine1] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [AddressLine2] [varchar](150) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_StudentAddress] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AddressID] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

When I inserted a new row into `[dbo].[Person]` like `[FirstName]`, it creates a `[BusinessEntityID]` automatically and increments one at a time. I want to use that `[BusinessEntityID]` value and insert it into `[AddressID]` and create space for address information of this employee to enter it later.

Is it possible with triggers? I added this trigger but nothing happens:

```
ALTER TRIGGER /*OR CREATE*/ [dbo].[auto_inc] 
ON [dbo].[Person]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Address(AddressID) SELECT p.BusinessEntityID FROM [Person] p
    UPDATE [Address]  SET AddressID = p.BusinessEntityID FROM [Person] p
END
```

Comment: First of all, it would have to be an `AFTER INSERT` trigger, and it would have to be on the `dbo.Person` table..... and secondly: you're not referencing the `Inserted` pseudo table which contains the rows that have been inserted - so how do you expect to get the newly inserted `BusinessEntityId` values?? And thirdly: the `AddressId` on `dbo.Address` **also** is an `IDENTITY` column, so you shouldn't just insert your own values into it - let SQL Server handle that .....

Comment: @marc_s   Sorry I'm a newbie of theese things There is a part I don't fully understand. I've edited commands, moved trigger to `Person` table,  removed `IDENTITY` from `Address` but nothing changed... I just wanted to move id of related row.. It musn't be hard af.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture the identity values inserted into the `Person` table - you need to have an `AFTER INSERT` trigger and you need to look at the `Inserted` pseudo table inside the trigger, to find out which rows have been inserted. Those can be **multiple rows** - so you need to handle this accordingly.

But do you **really** want to add an "empty" address to a newly created Person via the `BusinessEntityId`?? That creates tons of empty addresses - to what benefit?? Also: the way you have set this up right now, one person can only ever have exactly **one address** - that's also probably not a very good idea.

So if you **really** want to do this - you need a trigger something like this:

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[auto_inc] 
ON [dbo].[Person]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Address (AddressID) 
        SELECT p.BusinessEntityID 
        FROM Inserted;
END
```

But again - I think this is all wrong from a logic perspective. I would set up the `Address` table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Address
(
    -- use an IDENTITY for the unique ID for each address
    AddressID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,

    -- link the address to a person - this way, one person can have *multiple* addresses
    BusinessEntityID INT NOT NULL,
    AddressLine1 VARCHAR(150) NULL,
    AddressLine2 VARCHAR(150) NULL,
    -- more colums, like "AddressType" or something....

    CONSTRAINT PK_Address
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (AddressID ASC),
    -- establish foreign key constraint to Person
    CONSTRAINT FK_Address_Person
        FOREIGN KEY (BusinessEntityId) REFERENCES dbo.Person (BusinessEntityId)
)
```

and I would **NOT** automatically insert an empty address for every person you create - what for??

Comment: The thing is, we are designing a website for the term project where we get the data from the database and apply crud operations on it.  (Create, Update, Delete). We enter values ​​for the Person table on the website.  However, we cannot add any value to the address table since the same id is not synchronized to the address part.  So we thought that keeping businessid and addresid equal and synchronous could solve the problem.

Comment: @KeremYavuz At this point, it is impossible to have a meaningful discussion with all the edits made to your original post. But when you choose to use an identity column as the primary key, you are abdicating any role in the assignment of that value. But that is contradicted by your attempt to "align" them. Rarely is it a good idea to "align" PK values between related tables - and doing so requires the dependent table to NOT use identity. You have a design flaw that you cannot (mostly) code around.